# Jmeter Script recorder with Firefox not letting user bypass Authentication

Tags: windows, firefox, jmeter, recorder

I have an issue I'm facing which Jmeter Script recorder and Firefox browser in Windows 10.

I have managed to add a project in Jmeter with the Recorder template and imported the generated
Certificate into the Firefox browser and also changed the proxy settings to point to the port
I have in Jmeter Test script recorder (8888) by changing the proxy to manual configuration.

But when I start recording I get to a point in where I need to authenticate myself at a certain point in a webpage (a prompt showing up) and I also enter the correct credentials but it just keeps redirecting back to the prompt all over again so I can't bypass it.

Are there settings I should change in some of the Jmeter properties files?

I need to say that the computer I'm trying this with has proxy settings which are fixed and cant be changed when looking into wifi settings in control panel

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to deal with external authentication types like

- [basic HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager)
- [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))

So if you want to record the end-to-end flow you need to add properly configured HTTP Authorization Manager to your recording template test plan. The configuration details will differ depending on the server configuration, see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more details (you will need this setup in any case for replaying the recorded scripts)

Alternative solutions:

1. Disable proxy for this particular login request like:

   - Record all the steps including login - it will produce relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers
   - Disable proxy
   - Perform login
   - Enable proxy
   - Continue recording
2. Use a 3rd-party recording solution like [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)